# page view count increaes by two each time its loaded

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php code:

```
@mysql_query("UPDATE mp3 SET views = views+1 WHERE id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
```

I have that in my header with some other PHP, every time I load the page, the view count goes up by 2 instead of one, what would be the cause of this? I checked the script over and everything looks fine. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at access.log?

Comment: Activate query logging of your database and see if the query is really only issued once.

Comment: If this is in a separate php file that you're including in your script, are you using [include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)? Perhaps, check for a circular include somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS file or  section for a URL background that is empty.  That is the most common quirk that produces a double-retrieval.

Failing that, have a look in Firefox-Firebug / Chrome developer tools or something similar for which part of the code is causing the page to be loaded twice each time